# Regex to match string from the back

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say we have a string `"text\t1\nText that has to be extracted"` what regex can be used so that we check the string from the back that is from the last `"` to `n` because the start of the string can change. In this case, I need to get only `Text that has to be extracted`. What generic regex can we use here?

I used this `(?<=\\n1\\n)(.*)(?=“)` but this will not work if the pattern before `n` changes to `n2` or `ntext`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to match the digit that's on its own line before the last line?

Comment: i am trying to match the string between n and the " @OnlineCop so the extracted text would be "Text that has to be extracted"

Comment: @anubhava this matches the entire string

Comment: its not new line @anubhava its part of the string

Comment: Ok use `/.*\\n([^"]+)"$/` and grab captured group #1

Comment: Probably you didn't look at captured group. Anyway `(?<=\\n)[^"\\]+(?="$)` should also work

Comment: This works perfectly @anubhava thank you

Comment: can you post this as an answer? @anubhava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just split and take the last element?

```js
var item = "text\n1\nText that has to be extracted";
var last = item.split(/\n/g).reverse()[0];
console.log(last) // "Text that has to be extracted"
```

Comment: unfortunately splitting is not an option here

Comment: Could you explain why? @BijinAbraham

Comment: so the reason why i can't use split is that our org has a tool that takes in string matched from the regex. I would need to extract the string and then use it in the js script. this is kind of the first step.

Comment: this is something that is an internal issue

Comment: Then if you must, try: [`(?<=\\n)(?:.(?!\\n))+(?="$)`](https://regex101.com/r/5N9tcr/1)

Comment: @BijinAbraham, glad it helped. You got an answer down by another user that's perfectly fine allready =)

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```sh
/(?<=\\n)[^"\\]+(?="$)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJTQ11/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\\n)`: Lookbehind to make sure we have a `\n` before the current position
- `[^"\\]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `"` and not `\`
- `(?="$)`: Make sure we have a `"` before line end ahead

Answer (score 1):

`/^(\d+)\n([^\n"]+)"$/` may have some edge cases, but will find the number (one or more digits), followed by a newline, followed by any character that is neither newline nor a double quote, followed by a literal double quote.

This would require that the double quote occurs immediately before the end-of-line (EOL), but if that's not required (for example, if you have a semi-colon after the closing quote), remove `$` from the end.

### Edit

Just noticed that it's the literal text `\n` and not a newline character.

`/(?<=\\n)(\d+)\\n((?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*)"/`

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/etqNrD/1)

#### Breakdown:

- `(?<=\\n)` looks for a `\` followed by the letter `n`.
- `(\d+)` captures the 1-or-more digits.
- `\\n` matches a literal `\` followed by the letter `n`.
- `(...*)` matches some text that repeats 0 or more times.
- `(?:...|...)` matches any character that are neither a literal `\` character nor a double quote character... OR a literal `\` character that is followed by "anything" so you can have `\n` or `\"` etc. The entire group is matched repeatedly.
- `"` at the end ensures that you're inside (well, we hope) a double-quoted string on the same line.

Comment: With this regex n1\nText that has to be extracted" is getting extracted. how can I get only Text that has to be extracted

Comment: If you don't want the digit on the line right before the text, add that, plus the `\\n` into the look-behind: `/(?<=\\n\d+\\n)((?:...)*)"/`

Comment: the problem here is that everything except the string between nText that has to be extracted" can change